# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telegram' after pip install

Tags: installation, pip, python-telegram-bot

After running `pip install python-telegram-bot`, I'm getting this error that the 'telegram' module is not found.

Under `pip list` I see that my python-telegram-bot package is installed version 13.2

Is anyone else getting this error?

Comment: Hint: 2 different Pythons.

Comment: Indeed it might be due to different Python installation. I am using Mac which comes with python 2.  I installed a separate python using brew and I forgot about it.  If you install python using brew, you can check the location of python binary using "brew list python@3.9".

Answer (score 0):

Try another way to install it

first remove it
`pip3 uninstall python-telegram-bot`

Clone and install

```
git clone https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot
cd python-telegram-bot
python3 setup.py install
pip3 install python-telegram-bot
```

It should work

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem - for me the issue was that I was trying to run my code from a module called `telegram.py`. Newbie mistake I know...

Answer (score 0):

`pip3 install python-telegram-bot`

Install it in outside of virutal environment in terminal. Also unintall  `telegram`. `python-telegram-bot` is sufficient for Telegram bot. In my case it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Do 1-2 via terminal and 4 on your IDE:**

> Install pip install telegram Install pip install python-telegram-bot
> If you are using a virtual environment, make sure it is activated
> Lastly, **import from telegram.ext import ***

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this is how I solved it:

1. Open Windows PowerShell as an administrator.
2. Run the following command: `Get-ExecutionPolicy`.
3. If the previous command shows it is set to `restricted`, change it to allow remote sign using `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`.
4. Open your terminal and run `pip install python-telegram-bot` to install the bot again.